# How do I set an existing Unity prefab's current scale to be 1, 1, 1

Tags: unity-game-engine, prefab

I have a prefab in Unity whose scale I have tweaked. I would like its current scale to be considered 1, 1, 1. This will simplify some other game mechanics I am coding.

Comment: Give it a parent with the correct scale

Comment: Set the prefab (select in project folder) scale to 1 1 1. Revert the scale of your prefab instance. (richtclick -> revert)

Comment: @rbcode, can you clarify this a bit? I am not finding the revert option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create an empty object. Let's call it `NewObj`.
- Add you tweaked object as a child to the `NewObj`.
- Operate on the `NewObj` with (1,1,1) scale

Comment: Haven't you seen that there is already a comment 6 mins ago you posted with the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can reparent all child objects (to parent == null), change scale of your root object to 1,1,1 and drag childs inside again, they will maintain the current size if you do it like that.

If you have a Mesh Renderer on your root object you should go to models import settings and change scale there

[image: Model scale in import settings]